# Error: the installation or removal of a software packgae failed 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, update-manager

I'm new to Ubuntu (14.04 LTS) and appreciate any help. The update manager seems to have a problem, but no specific error message is given, only the above mentioned. I had a look thru similar threads here but they all deal with a specific problem.. I tried to update via the terminal but still no success. Thanks again for any suggestions!

```
klingone@tiefenrausch:~$ pastebinit /var/log/apt/history.log
The program 'pastebinit' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install pastebinit
klingone@tiefenrausch:~$ sudo apt-get install pastebinit
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  pastebinit
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 75 not upgraded.
Need to get 14,9 kB of archives.
After this operation, 168 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty/main pastebinit all 1.4-3 [14,9 kB]
Fetched 14,9 kB in 0s (73,5 kB/s)   
Selecting previously unselected package pastebinit.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
klingone@tiefenrausch:~$ 

klingone@tiefenrausch:~$ sudo dpkg --reconfigure -a
dpkg: error: unknown option --reconfigure

Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages [*];
Use 'apt' or 'aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;

Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through 'less' or 'more' !
klingone@tiefenrausch:~$ 

klingone@tiefenrausch:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
klingone@tiefenrausch:~$
```

also tried the following, but back to square 1..

```
> klingone@tiefenrausch:~$ sudo apt-get -f install Reading package
> lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading state
> information... Done 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 75
> not upgraded. klingone@tiefenrausch:~$ sudo apt-get clean
> klingone@tiefenrausch:~$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
> Ign http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br trusty InRelease Get:1
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br trusty-updates InRelease [65,9
> kB]   Hit http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br trusty-backports
> InRelease             Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease   
> Get:2 http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br trusty-security InRelease
> [65,9 kB]  Hit http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br trusty Release.gpg
> Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                       
> Get:3 http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br trusty-updates/main Sources
> [274 kB] Ign http://archive.canonical.com trusty InRelease            
> Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release                           
> Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release.gpg                   
> Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources        Get:4
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br trusty-updates/restricted Sources
> [5.352 B] Get:5 http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br
> trusty-updates/universe Sources [154 kB] Hit
> http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release                           
> Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                
> Get:6 http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br trusty-updates/multiverse
> Sources [5.928 B] Get:7 http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br
> trusty-updates/main i386 Packages [724 kB] Hit
> http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner Sources                   
> Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner i386 Packages         
> Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner Translation-en        
> Get:8 http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br trusty-updates/restricted
> i386 Packages [15,6 kB] Get:9 http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br
> trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages [360 kB] Get:10
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br trusty-updates/multiverse i386
> Packages [13,6 kB] Hit http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br
> trusty-updates/main Translation-en     Hit
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br trusty-updates/multiverse
> Translation-en Hit http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br
> trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en Hit
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br trusty-updates/universe
> Translation-en Hit http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br
> trusty-backports/main Sources          Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com
> trusty/main Translation-en_US               Hit
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br trusty-backports/restricted
> Sources Hit http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br
> trusty-backports/universe Sources Hit
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br trusty-backports/multiverse
> Sources Hit http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br trusty-backports/main
> i386 Packages Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en
> Hit http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br trusty-backports/restricted
> i386 Packages Hit http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br
> trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages Hit
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br trusty-backports/multiverse i386
> Packages Hit http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br
> trusty-backports/main Translation-en Hit
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br trusty-backports/multiverse
> Translation-en Hit http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br
> trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en Hit
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br trusty-backports/universe
> Translation-en Get:11 http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br
> trusty-security/main Sources [113 kB] Get:12
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br trusty-security/restricted
> Sources [4.035 B] Get:13 http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br
> trusty-security/universe Sources [36,2 kB] Get:14
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br trusty-security/multiverse
> Sources [2.764 B] Get:15 http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br
> trusty-security/main i386 Packages [435 kB] Get:16
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br trusty-security/restricted i386
> Packages [12,7 kB] Get:17 http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br
> trusty-security/universe i386 Packages [127 kB] Get:18
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br trusty-security/multiverse i386
> Packages [5.172 B] Hit http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br
> trusty-security/main Translation-en    Hit
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br trusty-security/multiverse
> Translation-en Hit http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br
> trusty-security/restricted Translation-en Hit
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br trusty-security/universe
> Translation-en Hit http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br trusty Release
> Hit http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br trusty/main Sources          
> Hit http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br trusty/restricted Sources    
> Hit http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br trusty/universe Sources      
> Hit http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br trusty/multiverse Sources    
> Hit http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br trusty/main i386 Packages    
> Hit http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br trusty/restricted i386
> Packages        Hit http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br
> trusty/universe i386 Packages          Hit
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br trusty/multiverse i386 Packages  
> Hit http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br trusty/main Translation-en   
> Hit http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br trusty/multiverse
> Translation-en       Hit http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br
> trusty/restricted Translation-en       Hit
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br trusty/universe Translation-en   
> Ign http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br trusty/main Translation-en_US
> Ign http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br trusty/multiverse
> Translation-en_US    Ign http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br
> trusty/restricted Translation-en_US    Ign
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br trusty/universe Translation-en_US
> Fetched 2.421 kB in 12s (189 kB/s)                                    
> Reading package lists... Done Reading package lists... Done Building
> dependency tree        Reading state information... Done Calculating
> upgrade... Done The following packages were automatically installed
> and are no longer required:   libhdb9-heimdal libkdc2-heimdal Use
> 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them. The following packages will be
> upgraded:   apt apt-transport-https apt-utils dpkg firefox
> firefox-locale-en fuseiso   gir1.2-soup-2.4 libapt-inst1.5
> libapt-pkg4.12 libdpkg-perl liblcms2-2   libldb1 libmm-glib0 libmms0
> libnautilus-extension1a libnss-winbind   liboxideqt-qmlplugin
> liboxideqtcore0 liboxideqtquick0 libpam-winbind   libpcre3
> libpoppler-glib8 libpoppler44 libsmbclient libsnmp-base libsnmp30  
> libsoup-gnome2.4-1 libsoup2.4-1 libssl1.0.0 libtalloc2 libtasn1-6
> libtdb1   libtevent0 libvlc5 libvlccore7 libwbclient0 linux-firmware
> modemmanager   nautilus nautilus-data oneconf oneconf-common
> openjdk-7-jre   openjdk-7-jre-headless openssl oxideqt-codecs-extra
> poppler-utils python-ldb   python-oneconf python-samba python-talloc
> python-tdb python3-oneconf samba   samba-common samba-common-bin
> samba-dsdb-modules samba-libs   samba-vfs-modules simple-scan
> smbclient tdb-tools thunderbird   thunderbird-gnome-support
> thunderbird-locale-en thunderbird-locale-en-us   tzdata tzdata-java
> vlc vlc-data vlc-nox vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-pulse   winbind 75
> upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. Need to
> get 208 MB of archives. After this operation, 50,2 MB of additional
> disk space will be used. Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y Get:1
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main dpkg
> i386 1.17.5ubuntu5.6 [1.939 kB] Get:2
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> libapt-pkg4.12 i386 1.0.1ubuntu2.13 [633 kB] Get:3
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main apt
> i386 1.0.1ubuntu2.13 [954 kB] Get:4
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> libpcre3 i386 1:8.31-2ubuntu2.3 [141 kB] Get:5
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> libapt-inst1.5 i386 1.0.1ubuntu2.13 [58,4 kB] Get:6
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> libssl1.0.0 i386 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.19 [782 kB] Get:7
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> libtasn1-6 i386 3.4-3ubuntu0.4 [42,9 kB] Get:8
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> liblcms2-2 i386 2.5-0ubuntu4.1 [129 kB] Get:9
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> libtalloc2 i386 2.1.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 [26,3 kB] Get:10
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> python-ldb i386 1:1.1.24-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 [28,5 kB] Get:11
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> python-tdb i386 1.3.8-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 [10,7 kB] Get:12
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> libtdb1 i386 1.3.8-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 [39,1 kB] Get:13
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> libtevent0 i386 0.9.28-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 [27,1 kB] Get:14
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> samba-dsdb-modules i386 2:4.3.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 [216 kB] Get:15
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe
> libnss-winbind i386 2:4.3.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 [12,8 kB] Get:16
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe
> libpam-winbind i386 2:4.3.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 [28,3 kB] Get:17
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> winbind i386 2:4.3.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 [415 kB] Get:18
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> libwbclient0 i386 2:4.3.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 [31,5 kB] Get:19
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> libsmbclient i386 2:4.3.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 [53,5 kB] Get:20
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> smbclient i386 2:4.3.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 [324 kB] Get:21
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main samba
> i386 2:4.3.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 [905 kB] Get:22
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> samba-common-bin i386 2:4.3.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 [513 kB] Get:23
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> samba-common all 2:4.3.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 [82,9 kB] Get:24
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> python-talloc i386 2.1.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 [7.636 B] Get:25
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> python-samba i386 2:4.3.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 [970 kB] Get:26
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> tdb-tools i386 1.3.8-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 [20,4 kB] Get:27
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> samba-vfs-modules i386 2:4.3.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 [257 kB] Get:28
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> samba-libs i386 2:4.3.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 [5.136 kB] Get:29
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> libldb1 i386 1:1.1.24-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 [108 kB] Get:30
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> libmm-glib0 i386 1.0.0-2ubuntu1.1 [127 kB] Get:31
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe
> libmms0 i386 0.6.2-3ubuntu2.1 [28,7 kB] Get:32
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> libpoppler44 i386 0.24.5-2ubuntu4.4 [678 kB] Get:33
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> libpoppler-glib8 i386 0.24.5-2ubuntu4.4 [82,0 kB] Get:34
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> libsnmp-base all 5.7.2~dfsg-8.1ubuntu3.2 [203 kB] Get:35
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> libsnmp30 i386 5.7.2~dfsg-8.1ubuntu3.2 [734 kB] Get:36
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> libsoup2.4-1 i386 2.44.2-1ubuntu2.1 [226 kB] Get:37
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> libsoup-gnome2.4-1 i386 2.44.2-1ubuntu2.1 [4.960 B] Get:38
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe
> vlc-plugin-notify i386 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.2 [5.614 B] Get:39
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe
> vlc-plugin-pulse i386 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.2 [17,0 kB] Get:40
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe
> vlc i386 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.2 [1.198 kB] Get:41
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe
> libvlccore7 i386 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.2 [349 kB] Get:42
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe
> vlc-data all 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.2 [4.767 kB] Get:43
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe
> vlc-nox i386 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.2 [1.999 kB] Get:44
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe
> libvlc5 i386 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.2 [41,9 kB] Get:45
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> openjdk-7-jre i386 7u101-2.6.6-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 [168 kB] Get:46
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> tzdata-java all 2016d-0ubuntu0.14.04 [69,6 kB] Get:47
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> tzdata all 2016d-0ubuntu0.14.04 [167 kB] Get:48
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> openjdk-7-jre-headless i386 7u101-2.6.6-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 [40,2 MB]
> Get:49 http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/
> trusty-updates/main apt-utils i386 1.0.1ubuntu2.13 [172 kB] Get:50
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> apt-transport-https i386 1.0.1ubuntu2.13 [25,3 kB] Get:51
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> openssl i386 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.19 [480 kB] Get:52
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> firefox i386 46.0+build5-0ubuntu0.14.04.2 [44,4 MB] Get:53
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> firefox-locale-en i386 46.0+build5-0ubuntu0.14.04.2 [602 kB] Get:54
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe
> fuseiso i386 20070708-3+deb7u1ubuntu14.04.1 [19,8 kB] Get:55
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> gir1.2-soup-2.4 i386 2.44.2-1ubuntu2.1 [22,5 kB] Get:56
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> libdpkg-perl all 1.17.5ubuntu5.6 [179 kB] Get:57
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> libnautilus-extension1a i386 1:3.10.1-0ubuntu9.11 [51,9 kB] Get:58
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> linux-firmware all 1.127.22 [33,2 MB] Get:59
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> modemmanager i386 1.0.0-2ubuntu1.1 [473 kB] Get:60
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> nautilus-data all 1:3.10.1-0ubuntu9.11 [50,7 kB] Get:61
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> nautilus i386 1:3.10.1-0ubuntu9.11 [485 kB] Get:62
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> poppler-utils i386 0.24.5-2ubuntu4.4 [115 kB] Get:63
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> simple-scan i386 3.12.3-0ubuntu1 [134 kB] Get:64
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> thunderbird-locale-en i386 1:38.7.2+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 [350 kB]
> Get:65 http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/
> trusty-updates/main thunderbird i386 1:38.7.2+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
> [32,9 MB] Get:66 http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/
> trusty-updates/main thunderbird-gnome-support i386
> 1:38.7.2+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 [8.536 B] Get:67
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> thunderbird-locale-en-us all 1:38.7.2+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 [9.972
> B] Get:68 http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/
> trusty-updates/main liboxideqt-qmlplugin i386 1.14.7-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
> [189 kB] Get:69 http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/
> trusty-updates/main liboxideqtquick0 i386 1.14.7-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 [266
> kB] Get:70 http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/
> trusty-updates/main liboxideqtcore0 i386 1.14.7-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 [28,2
> MB] Get:71 http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/
> trusty-updates/main oxideqt-codecs-extra i386 1.14.7-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
> [902 kB] Get:72 http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/
> trusty-updates/main oneconf-common all 0.3.7.14.04.1 [6.042 B] Get:73
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> python3-oneconf all 0.3.7.14.04.1 [19,5 kB] Get:74
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> oneconf all 0.3.7.14.04.1 [5.458 B] Get:75
> http://ubuntu-archive.locaweb.com.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main
> python-oneconf all 0.3.7.14.04.1 [19,7 kB] Fetched 208 MB in 3min 27s
> (1.002 kB/s)                                         Extracting
> templates from packages: 100% Preconfiguring packages ... E:
> Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
> klingone@tiefenrausch:~$

100% Preconfiguring packages ... dpkg: unrecoverable fatal
> error, aborting:  reading files list for package
> 'libgudev-1.0-0:i386': Input/output error E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg
> returned an error code (2) klingone@tiefenrausch:~$
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39431/discussion-on-question-by-greg-error-the-installation-or-removal-of-a-software).

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get autoremove`

After the process is finished

```
sudo apt-get install -f && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Hope this will fix your problem.

Comment: Ok, tried it, but no success. Same error messages are coming up.

Answer (score 0):

This could have nothing to do with dpkg as the error shown is Input/Output error, this could mean that for system file has become corrupt.You can check is your  system file is corrupt by running

```
fsck /dev/sXY
```

where sXY is your root partition which can found by using `lsblk`(your root partition is the one which has mount point "/")
If the number of bad sectors is low.Then try this

1. make a backup of the file `status` located in /var/lib/dpkg
2. Run `pkexec /var/lib/dpkg/status`
3. And delete the line for the package which is causing the problem(in your case `libgudev-1.0-0:i386`)
4. save and exit.
5. Then run `sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt-get install -f`

Source:[editing status file](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1232143&p=10010092#post10010092),[bad sectors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/556626/how-do-i-repair-dpkg-and-apt-get)